# Recursive Huffman Coding in Python

Tags: python, huffman-code

I was asked to create functions in Python WITHOUT using loops and trees to represent Huffman Coding. I created function which from this input:

```
[('a',4),('b',10),('c',15),('d',18),('e',42),('f',11)]
```

gives this output:

```
('e', (('f', ('a', 'b')), ('c', 'd')))
```

Now, I am supposed to create function which encodes this output into

```
[('e','0' ) , ('f','100') , ('a', '1010') , ( 'b' , '1011' ) , ('c', '110') , ('d','111' ) ]
```

I have no idea how to (without using loops) change tuple to list and in the same time adding `1` and `0` to certain elements.

Comment: Do you know what a recursive function is? Because I'm pretty sure that "WITHOUT using loops" means you're supposed to write a recursive function. Look at the input format: it's a tuple of two things, each of which is either a letter or another tuple. That should tell you how to decompose it recursively.

Comment: Study recursion more.  **Hint:** Recursion is a loop, just in a different form.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how this is "without using trees"; a nested list (or tuple) is one of the most obvious ways to represent a tree (as half the exercises in any Lisp-based textbook prove…).

Comment: Are you asking us to write the solution for you?

Comment: I dont know how to comment "I'm not sure how this is "without using trees"". This is the task, I'm not supposed to question if it's useful/clever etc.

Comment: No i am not asking for a soultion. I am asking if there exists built-in function which changes tuples into list.

Comment: It didn't occur to you to even try `list()`?

Comment: Your question says "change tuple to list and in the same time adding 1 and 0 to certain elements". There's obviously no built-in function that does that. If you're just asking how to change a tuple into a list, then the whole rest of the question is extraneous noise. If you're asking how to do what you've asked for, then your last comment makes no sense.

Comment: Really? There's no built-in function that does that? And is there any built-in function that makes a coffee for me? Thanks for help!

Comment: Why exactly do you want to change tuples to lists? You may have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/150985) -- just mentioning "Recursive Huffman" isn't enough information.

Answer (score 0):

`list()` -> new empty list

`list(iterable)` -> new list initialized from iterable's items

A tuple is an iterable, so calling `list` on one will yield a list of its elements.